# Can't drag circles like example in book(Applet)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, applet

So my university uses the book Java programming from problem analysis to program design by DS Malik(ISBN: 978-1-111-53053-2) and in one of the examples I copied the code word for word. It runs but doesn't work the way its supposed too. What you're supposed to do is be able to click and drag circles that populate the screen in an applet. If anyone is interested in the programming example its 12-10. I have provided the code from eclipse. Any and all help is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class FreeDrawApplet extends JApplet implements MouseMotionListener
{



    //instance variables
    ColorCircle[] myGraph;

    final int NUM_CIRCLES = 7;
    final int WIDTH = 400;
    final int HEIGHT = 400;



    public class ColorCircle
    {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public void setx(int iNewX)
        {
            x = iNewX;
        }
        public void sety(int iNewY)
        {
            x = iNewY;
        }
        public void paint (Graphics g)
        {
            g.fillOval(x-10, y-10, 20, 20);
        }
        public boolean selected(int iXcoord, int iYcoord)
        {
            if ((iXcoord >= x-10) && (iXcoord <= x+10) && (iYcoord >= y-10) && (iYcoord <= y+10))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

    }//end of public class circle

    public void init ()
    {
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        myGraph = new ColorCircle[NUM_CIRCLES];

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CIRCLES; i++)
        {
            ColorCircle myVertex = new ColorCircle();

            myVertex.setx((int)(Math.random() * (WIDTH-50)));

            myVertex.sety((int)(Math.random() * (HEIGHT-100)));

            myGraph[i] = myVertex;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try to drag any one of the colored circles ", "Information", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }//end of method

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Color[] myColor = {Color.black, Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green, Color.cyan, Color.orange, Color.yellow};

        if(NUM_CIRCLES > 0)
            for(int i =0; i < NUM_CIRCLES; i++)
            {
                g.setColor(myColor[i]);
                myGraph[i].paint(g);
            }

    }//end of paint method

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
    {
        int iX = event.getX();
        int iY = event.getY();

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CIRCLES; i++)
        {
            if(myGraph[i].selected(iX, iY))
            {
                myGraph[i].setx(iX);
                myGraph[i].sety(iY);
                break;
            }

        }

        repaint();
    }


    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent p1)
    {
    }


}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Applets have become completely unworkable for sites dealing to 'all comers' on the internet.  Browser makers have, or are set to completely remove support for them.  It is best to transition away from applets to pure JS/HTML sooner rather than later.

Comment: Yes he knows this, however one of the assignments in the book requires an applet. I want to better understand this code because I don't understaand how gui's work in general.

Comment: *"I want to better understand this code because I don't understaand how gui's work in general."* Then you're setting up a huge wall by focusing on applets. Most people on SO did not know / care enough about them to help in the past. I am the top ranked provider of [tag:applet] answers on SO (and wrote the [info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) on them and many related technologies). Even ***I*** could not be bothered with them (thinking about or helping with) anymore. Get a new book, and if needed, a new teacher. Or less radically, just do the work as applications.

Comment: BTW - most developers who might help on a problem, will copy/paste, compile & run code that ppl are asking for help with. The thing is, Oracle deprecated applets and removed the classes from Java .. 9 (? or so), which means most people can no longer even compile code based on applets.

Comment: Well I defintely can't get a new teacher or book so thats out of the question. Where can I find a good guide to applications?

Comment: See [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).